# How to add the same string to all the elements of a txt file using SED in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file called "a.txt" which contains many line. In each line there is only one string (a name). I want to add a string such as "imp_" to the beginning of all these elements. How can I do this using SED?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution#t=201610191007058517981

Comment: You need to provide a sample i/p and expected o/p along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I can not test these but maybe:

```
sed -e 's/^/imp_/' file
```

or to edit the file in-place use

```
sed -i -e 's/^/imp_/' file
```

`awk` could also be used

```
awk '$0="imp_"$0' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed 's/yourstring/imp_&/' <<< "some text yourstring other text"
some text imp_yourstring other text
```

In the substitution string, `&` outputs the pattern found.